# Cannot debug on Windows 10 Phone (build 10572)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to debug a Universal Windows 10 app on my Windows 10 Phone, but it keeps giving me this error:

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: PasswordsUniversal, Configuration: Debug     ARM ------
1>Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during  bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '3334F9-6231E-310b-A221-7B036E23D4A4E'.': 
1>SEHException - External component has thrown an exception.
1>Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found. 
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I already uninstalled the phone from my computer, and I restarted both devices. What else can I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered the root of the problem: I am using Windows 10 Mobile Insider Preview, so I have the latests patches for my cell phone, and I wasn't using the latest SDK. Make sure to have the latest version of the SDK when using the Insider Preview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `Developer Mode` in `Settings->Update & Security->For developers` on your phone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already have that configuration in place :(

Comment: Have you soft reset the phone since enabling?

Comment: Yes, I aready resetted it. I also uninstalled the phone drivers on my pc, and restarted the pc. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I found a very similar question to this one on a MSDN forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/3f1a4a71-f402-44e9-b18e-f6b2e41796d0/uwpdeployment-fails-on-phone-build-10572?forum=wpdevelop